# Do I need to call super when overriding data source and delegate methods in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, subclass

Consider the following snippet that derives a custom view controller from `UITableViewController`.

```
class Controller: UITableViewController {
    ...
)

// MARK: - Table View Data Source

extension Controller {

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // call super?
        ...
    }

}

// MARK: - Table View Delegate

extension Controller {

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        // call super?
        ...
    }

}
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/index.html) says:

> You may override loadView or any other superclass method, but if you do be sure to invoke the superclass implementation of the method, usually as the first method call.

My question is, does this also apply to the methods in the protocols `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` to which `UITableViewController` conforms?

Calling `super` in data source methods does not make much sense to me since usually you define your own content using these methods. I am, however, not sure about the delegate methods. Calling `super` in `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath` for instance does not seem to have any obvious effect though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to call super in these cases. The documentation quote you included in your original question refers to overriding the super class methods. However, `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` are protocols (and not your class' superclass) and the methods you mentioned were declared especially for you to implement them the way that fits you best.

Comment: But aren't the protocol methods superclass methods (`UITableViewController`)? Because the superclass (and only by inheritance the custom subclass) is what conforms to the protocols (`UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDataSource`). Otherwise, you wouldn't need the `override` keyword when overriding the methods in the custom subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it doesn't make sense to do it in this case and is not something you should be doing.